# HTML attribute not working with jquery variable when select with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am getting id of clicked element and validating that next element of that clicked element having attribute `data-parent` and then calling `show()` but it's not working

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.clickme').click(function() {
    var abc = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    if (jQuery('#' + abc).next().attr('data-parent')) {
      jQuery("li[data-parent=abc]").show();
    } else {
      jQuery("li[data-parent=abc]").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="abcd" class="clickme">0</li>
<li data-parent="abcd" display="none">1</li>
```

Comment: `"li[data-parent=abc]"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's several issues here.

- The HTML is invalid. The `<li>` elements need closing `</li>` tags, and need to be wrapped in a `<ul>`
- `display` is not a HTML attribute. You need to use CSS instead for that.
- You're using the `this` reference to the element to build a jQuery object to get the `id`, to select the same element again. Just use `this` to build the jQuery object
- Using the value of `attr()` in an `if` condition will not work as you expect it to. If you're attempting to determine if an element exist use `length`
- You can just use `next()` with a selector to find the target element
- You can use `toggle()` to hide/show it on each click
- The `data-parent` value is `abcd`, not `abc`

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
    $(this).next('li[data-parent="abcd"]').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
li[data-parent] { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="abcd" class="clickme">aaaa</li>
  <li data-parent="abcd">bbbb</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, if you want to make the selection by data attribute dynamic, and related to the `id` of the clicked element you need to concatenate the `id` value in to the selector:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
    $(this).next(`li[data-parent="${this.id}"]`).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
li[data-parent] { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="abcd" class="clickme">abcd parent</li>
  <li data-parent="abcd">abcd child</li>
  <li id="foo" class="clickme">foo parent</li>
  <li data-parent="foo">foo child</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't want to hard code `abcd` in the `data-parent` in jquery instead I want to put variable name and when I put variable name it's not working

Comment: I just edited the answer to show you how to do that. Also note for future reference that you should explain requirements like that in the question.

Comment: can you explain this line `$(this).next(`li[data-parent="${this.id}"]`).toggle();` when I add `'` like this `$(this).next('li[data-parent="${this.id}"]').toggle();` it's not working

Comment: You have to use the backticks to delimit that as it's using a Template literal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: You can use traditional concatenation if you prefer though: `$(this).next('li[data-parent="' + this.id + '"]').toggle();`